# Looking for a good SNMP Browser to run under Windows

Tags: windows, snmp

I used to use [Getif](http://www.wtcs.org/snmp4tpc/getif.htm) for poking around inside [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) results from servers and devices. However it no longer works with Windows 7 and 64-bit.

I am looking for hopefully an open source bit of software that will allow me add [MIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base)'s as required and allow me to browse the MIB tree and send a request/walk off to a server to get results.

What do you all use?

Comment: Why community wiki? This seams like a perfectly valid question to me and that view appears to be supported by the upvotes.

Comment: I have seen similar questions shot down in flames. Dont really need the Rep, just a useful SNMP Browser :-)

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 10):

You may give a try at [MIB Browser from iReasoning](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml), the free version is only limited to the number of loaded MIBs (10 at once).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This tool is great, you can send and receive SNMP traps too. Very handy.

Comment: Try SnmpB, it's open-source and 100% free: https://bestmonitoringtools.com/free-mib-browser-download-snmpb/

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, Getif works for me on windows 7. Just try starting it in "XP compatibility mode" :)

Comment: I have to second this one. I've been using it for aaaaaaages, still gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

All of them sucks. but try one these. 
BlackOwl MIB Browser, Tamosoft Essential network tools or Colasoft Network analyzer

Comment: so, so true... I have yet to find a "good" MIB browser. I would pay for one that made the layout of the MIB trees easier to understand, and easier to walk a device and find out what values are available. Like maybe after you walk a device, give the ability filter out all the OIDs that are not available on that device and only see the relevant ones.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, SolarWinds has by far the best SNMP tools on Windows. I've also recently used [NetTools Pro](http://www.axencesoftware.com/index.php?action=NTPro) by Axence, and it seems reasonable. My windows machine is still XP though, so I can't vouch from them working on newer versions.

Comment: NetTools Pro and ManageEngine have the *best* MIB Browsers I've used, but they are all pretty bad really...

Answer (score 0):

Here's list of mib browsers that I've ever used:

1. Mibble mib browser http://www.mibble.org (free) ManageEngine
2. MibBrowser Free Tool
   http://www.manageengine.com/products/mibbrowser-free-tool (free)
3. OidView http://www.oidview.com (commercial)